# Many to many relationship validation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, backend, laravel-blade

I have 3 tables:

- Users - courses - user_courses ( many to many relationship)
- User [ id ] Course [ day - time - start_date - end_date ]
- User_Course [user_id - course_id ]

I want to validate that user can't enroll to two courses in same day and time and period from start_date to end_date This for api I receive course_id in request and i have logged user id Any help ! Thx

I validate that user can't enroll to same course twice

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom validation rule inside a form request to validate that.

To check if the courses period overlap, using `CarbonPeriod`'s `overlaps` method is pretty straight-forward.

Since I can't think of any validation rules that do that right away, I'm using the validator's `after` to register a callback method.

#### Multiple courses:

```php
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EnrollRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'courses' => ['required', 'array'],
            'courses.*' => ['required', 'exists:courses,id'],
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $user_courses = $this->user()->courses;

        $validator->after(function (Validator $validator) use ($user_courses) {
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $courses = Course::whereIn('id', $data['courses'])->get();

            foreach ($courses as $i => $course) {
                // check user hasn't enrolled in the course already
                if ($user_courses->contains($course) {
                    $validator->errors()->add("courses.$i", 'User is already enrolled in this course.');
                }

                // check if the course doesn't overlap with other courses the user has
                $course_period = CarbonPeriod::create($course->start_date, $course->end_date);
                foreach ($user_courses as $user_course) {
                    if ($couse_period->overlaps($user_course->start_date, $user_course->end_date)) {
                        $validator->errors()->add("courses.$i", 'Course overlaps.');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```php
// controller
public function enroll(EnrollRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->courses()->attach($request->validated()['courses']);
}
```

#### Single course

```php
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EnrollRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'course_id' => ['required', 'exists:courses,id'],
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $user_courses = $this->user()->courses;

        $validator->after(function (Validator $validator) use ($user_courses) {
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $course = Course::find($data['course_id']);

            // check user hasn't enrolled in the course already
            if ($user_courses->contains($course) {
                $validator->errors()->add("courses.$i", 'User is already enrolled in this course.');
            }

            // check if the course doesn't overlap with other courses the user has
            $course_period = CarbonPeriod::create($course->start_date, $course->end_date);
            foreach ($user_courses as $user_course) {
                if ($couse_period->overlaps($user_course->start_date, $user_course->end_date)) {
                    $validator->errors()->add('course_id', 'Course overlaps.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```php
// controller
public function enroll(EnrollRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->courses()->attach($request->validated()['course_id']);
}
```

- The documentation about CarbonPeriod is the bottom
  of https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests

Comment: As an alternative to `withValidator`, you can also create new  `Rule` classes that encapsulate the validation behavior and use them inside the `rules` method.